# GridView loads slow for large image resources

Tags: java, android, gridview, performance

I've been learning android programming for some days. I am creating an ebook application which reads images from the drawable folder. I've successfully implemented the pageviewer activity which loads bitmaps using asyncTask in background and shows a text "loading..." until loading is completed.

I wanted to show a pagelist in another activity using gridview so that user can scroll through a grid of pages and select any. I followed the android gridview tutorial and wasnt much problem. But since i have about 50 images in drawable and it seems gridview adapter shows the grid once all images are croped and placed in grid. It takes a lot of time to show the grid and its quite slow on scroll.

I was wondering if there was a better way to show the grid, asynchronously, like show the first item and then the 2nd and so on, instead of waiting for a long time and displaying the grid. I saw some topics like lazy load which seems similar to what i want, but they all show image from web, it was confusing. Hope i can get some sugestions, or if there is any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Fedor's Image Lazy Loader?

Here is the link: [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) ,

I know you want to implement it for GridView, but still you can refer the **ImageLoader** class given in the example code.

### Update:

You can even try this example [Lazy Loading GridView](http://blog.jamesbaca.net/?p=67). I haven't tried it, but as i found it, i thought it may be of your help.

Comment: I've seen that topic. I'll try that once i read more about hashmap and softreference. I'm new to android and java, guess i was looking for an easy way out. Thank you anyways, I'll bookmark that topic.

Answer (score 3):

The images you show are probably a bit too large to be used with GridView in their current form.

I guess you need the GridView to display thumbnails, so one possible approach would be to store a thumbnail sized copy of every page you have, and use those in the Grid.

You can also try switching hardware acceleration on in the manifest, that might help you with the scrolling once the images are small enough to load them faster. But afaik hw acceleration is only available in 3.0 and up.

Comment: I was also thinking of the same thing :) but thought it wouldn't give much impression to the customer. I'm gonna do that if i cant find any other apraoch. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Saved my life, I have been working like hell to improve the performance - by just doing that my app flies! Thanks!